# manager.hasChanges fails

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I had updated to breeze 1.5.1 and I have the next error:

```
Error: Unable to get property 'hasChanges' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (/breeze.debug.js:13935:7)
   at proto._hasChangesCore (/breeze.debug.js:13934:5)
   at proto.hasChanges (/breeze.debug.js:13910:5)
```

[image]

```
  proto._hasChangesCore = function (entityTypes) {
    entityTypes = checkEntityTypes(this, entityTypes);
    var entityGroups = getEntityGroups(this, entityTypes); //--> entityGroups = []
    return entityGroups.some(function (eg) {
      return eg.hasChanges(); //--> eg is undefined
    });
  };
```

Line that produce the error:

```
manager.hasChanges(entityType);
```

This error only occur when:

```
manager.getEntities(entityType).length == 0
```

I need to check if entityType has changes, but I don't want to get all entities of this entityType. In previous versions of breeze I check this with only:

```
manager.hasChanges(entityType);
```

How do this with breeze 1.5.1?

Please help me.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error:  http://i.imgur.com/hSPUT2D.png    
Tried calling `hasChanges` with the name of a type that does not exist in the metadata store as well as the name of a type that does exist in the metadata store but had no entities in the entitymanager... neither test caused the error.

Comment: Try call `hasChanges` with the name of a type that exist in the metadata store, but this type: `manager.getEntities(entityType).length == 0`. The items of name of type doesn't fill previously from server.

Comment: I'll try to repro later this week. If I can repro it, I'll get a fix into the repro at the same time and post back here.